# Set label font size from data column in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot using labels with varying font size.  For example:

```
plot "some_data_file" using 1:2:(20-$3) using labels font sprintf("Helvetica,%d",variable)
```

Or something to that effect.  The label's font size should be 20 minus the value in the third column.  This line doesn't work, but I think it displays what I'm trying to do.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`cities.dem`](http://gnuplot.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gnuplot/gnuplot/demo/cities.dem?view=log) demo on [gnuplot.info](http://gnuplot.info/) for a way to do this.

I'll steal the solution there, modified for you:

```
plot "some_data_file" using 2:3:(sprintf("{/Helvetica=%d %s}",\
    20-$4, stringcolumn(4))) with labels
```